# Flutter Layout Builder Resizing Issues using Expanded()

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a layout where 2 of my widgets are aligned to the bottom of the page and remain there when the window is resized. So far I use the following code and it works in keeping the footer at the bottom of the page:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarDesktop(),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                  minHeight: constraints.maxHeight, maxHeight: double.infinity),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    //height: 400,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "COMING SOON!",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  newsletterWidget(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: footerWidget(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

My issues it that I Want to also have the newsletter anchored to the bottom to resize with the footer. I have tried placing a column within the Expanded Widget however that just breaks the functionality for both, I also tried putting the newsletter widget within the footerwidget however the issue is the same. Is there a way for me to have 2 Expanded widgets? or an alternative way to have 2 rows within one Expanded

Edit:
This is my footer widget:

```
class footerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const footerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 40,
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                child: Icon(
                  IconData(0xe198, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                  size: 20,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "MyGameDevPal 2022. All rights reserved.",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              OnHoverButton(builder: (isHovered) {
                return IconButton(
                  color: isHovered ? HexColor('#2476c4') : Colors.white,
                  icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebook),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _launchUrlFacebook();
                  },
                );
              }),
              OnHoverButton(builder: (isHovered) {
                return IconButton(
                  color: isHovered ? HexColor('#2476c4') : Colors.white,
                  icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _launchUrlInstagram();
                  },
                );
              }),
              OnHoverButton(builder: (isHovered) {
                return IconButton(
                  color: isHovered ? HexColor('#2476c4') : Colors.white,
                  icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _launchUrlTwitter();
                  },
                );
              }),
              OnHoverButton(builder: (isHovered) {
                return IconButton(
                  color: isHovered ? HexColor('#2476c4') : Colors.white,
                  icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.youtube),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _launchUrlYoutube();
                  },
                );
              }),
              OnHoverButton(builder: (isHovered) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: IconButton(
                    color: isHovered ? HexColor('#2476c4') : Colors.white,
                    icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.discord),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _launchUrlDiscord();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include full widget with `footerWidget`

Comment: I included it above

Answer (score -2):

you can use Flixible instead of expanded tr it

Comment: Didn't work, acts the same way